# Rearrange the rows in a table without truncating them to reinsert?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table, for example,

```
Health condition    |   Description
-----------------------------------------------
OtherHealth         |   Other Health Care Needs
TraumaBrain         |   Traumatic Brain Injury
None                |   None
```

Now, I regret that I added the last column last. Now there are dependencies on this table so i cannot truncate and re-insert them. So I am looking for a way to bring the last row first.

Comment: The order of the row does not have any importance in a SQL table.

Answer (score 0):

To rearrange these two columns use

```
alter table t rename column "Health condition" to c1;
alter table t rename column "Description" to c2;
update t set c1=c2, c2=c1;
alter table t rename column c1 to "Description";
alter table t rename column c2 to "Health condition";
```